# Distinct Union on Select. Errors on ntext data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm pretty useless at SQL but I find myself having to write a stored procedure for a *very* simple keyphrase search.

I am trying to do a simple select on Name -using like %keyword%- then another select on Description -same keyword- and joining (union) the 2 selects.

However, I get the error:

```
The ntext data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.
```

I tried using `UNION ALL` but that returned duplicate rows in certain instances (depending on the keyword/phrase).

I also tried to work out using temp tables and selecting distinct on that, but that's where I got really confused.

**Rules:**

- I can't change the data type
- I need the rows from select on the 'Name' to be above the rows from the select on the 'Description'
- I can only use 1 stored procedure, and can't change the data adapter, as I'm plugging it into a system I have no control over.

**Further info:**

Table Columns (the important 2 I am working with are Name and Description):

```
ProductId   int
Name    varchar(255)
Introduction    varchar(255)
Description ntext
Material    ntext
Colour  varchar(255)
Active  bit
Dimensions  varchar(255)
Photo   varchar(255)
Price   decimal(10, 2)
DisplayOrder    int
ProductReference    varchar(255)
CategoryId  int
FriendlyURL varchar(1000)
```

SQL:

```
(SELECT        Products.ProductId, Name, Introduction, Description, Active, 
            Material, Colour, Dimensions, Photo, Price, DisplayOrder, FriendlyURL,
            ProductReference, Categories_Products_Lookup.CategoryId
FROM            Products INNER JOIN
                Categories_Products_Lookup ON 
                Products.ProductId = Categories_Products_Lookup.ProductId
WHERE           Active = 1 AND tProduct.Name like '%'+@Keyword+'%')
UNION
(SELECT        Products.ProductId, Name, Introduction, Description, Active, 
            Material, Colour, Dimensions, Photo, Price, DisplayOrder, FriendlyURL,
            ProductReference, Categories_Products_Lookup.CategoryId
FROM            ProductsINNER JOIN
                Categories_Products_Lookup ON 
                Products.ProductId = Categories_Products_Lookup.ProductId
WHERE           Active = 1 AND Products.Description like '%'+@Keyword+'%')
```

Any help getting out a table of distinct rows would be really appreciated. Also, explaining to me as a Layman would be great. :)

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on? If 2005+ are you able to change the datatype of the column to `nvarchar(max)`? `ntext` is deprecated and difficult to work with. `nvarchar(max)` is its replacement. Also is there a specific reason why you are using `UNION` here rather than `or`?

Comment: Hi Martin, I'm using 2008 R2. However, I don't think I can change the data type. There's a whole system running of it and I don't know what knock-on effects it will have to other areas.
What would using OR do? I wish to get results from both selects but have the selects from 'Name' coming out on top.

Comment: Well your posted query is a bit confusing and invalid as one branch mentions `tProduct` in the `Where` but there is no such table in the `FROM` and the other `Products` but assuming they are the same table. `WHERE Active = 1 AND (Products.Description like '%'+@Keyword+'%') or Products.Name like '%'+@Keyword+'%')` would do the same thing without having to scan the table and perform the join twice then merge the two results.

Comment: Sorry, yes, the tProduct & Products table are the same. I edited slightly before posting and missed a few changes.  Just tested the OR - it brings back the results ok, but in the wrong order. I want rows with the keyword in 'Name' to be above _any_ other rows. The seems to produce results in ID order.

Comment: That desired ordering wouldn't happen with your `UNION` query either even if you did a cast to get it working.

Comment: It seemed to work in tests when I used `UNION ALL`. It placed rows with the keyword in the 'Name' above rows with the keyword in 'Description'. The problem is if the keyword is too vague and pulls back a lot of results where the keyword is in the Name, the Description, and in the Name & Description. It adds duplicate rows for the latter.

Comment: When you replace `UNION ALL` with `UNION` they will get re-ordered in the process of duplicate elimination. (It isn't actually guaranteed to be the case for `UNION ALL` either)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments. It seems this is what you need.

```
SELECT Products.ProductId,
       Name,
       Introduction,
       Description,
       Active,
       Material,
       Colour,
       Dimensions,
       Photo,
       Price,
       DisplayOrder,
       FriendlyURL,
       ProductReference,
       Categories_Products_Lookup.CategoryId
FROM   Products
       INNER JOIN Categories_Products_Lookup
         ON Products.ProductId = Categories_Products_Lookup.ProductId
WHERE  Active = 1
       AND ( Products.Description like '%' + @Keyword + '%'
              or Products.Name like '%' + @Keyword + '%' )
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN Products.Name like '%' + @Keyword + '%' THEN 0
            ELSE 1
          END
```

You might want to consider using [Full Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) for this as searches with leading wildcards cannot use an index and always need to scan all the rows.

Comment: You're a genius! I think I may love you! :D  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

Use something like 'cast(Description as nvarchar(2000)) as Description' instead of ntext field names.

Comment: Hi Arvo, I tried your suggestion and replaced all references to Description with that cast statement, but it comes up with the same error:
`The ntext data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable`

Comment: @Deadly apply the same cast to `Material` as well (and any other `text` columns involved in the `UNION` operation)

Comment: Hi Arvo, Thanks for the answer. I'm sure it would have worked, but the one above offered a solution I could understand. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 5):

This answer is for others like me that won't have problems with duplicate rows.

`UNION ALL` is probably what you want.

See the [documentation for the UNION operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Perfect solution! I did not have duplicate problem.